# Elasticsearch fails in parsing datetime field coming from pymongo as object

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch, pymongo

I am trying to stream data from a mongoDB to Elasticsearch using both *pymongo* and the Python client *elasticsearch*.

I have set a mapping, I report here the snippet related to the field of interest:

> "updated_at": {
>               "type": "date",
>               "format": "dateOptionalTime"
>           }

My script grabs each document from the MongoDB using pymongo and tries indexing it into Elasticsearch as

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
es_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}])
db = mongo_client['my_db']
collection = db['my_collection']

for doc in collection.find():
    es_client.index(
         index='index_name', 
         doc_type='my_type', 
         id=str(doc['_id']), 
         body=json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
    )
```

The problem I have in running it is:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'MapperParsingException[failed to parse [updated_at]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [$date]]; ')

I believe the source of the problem is in the fact that pymongo serializes the field *updated_at* as a datetime.datetime object, as I can see if I print the doc in the for loop:

> u'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 31, 17, 18, 13, 17000)

This conflicts with Elasticsearch looking for an object of type *date* as specified in the mapping.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you're using

```
body=json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
```

but you should be using

```
body=doc
```

Doing that works for me, since it seems elasticsearch is caring for the aliasing of the dictionarly into a JSON document (of course, assuming doc is a dictionary, which I guess it is).

At least in the version of elasticsearch I'm using (2.x), datetime.datetime is correctly aliased, with no need of a mapping. For example, this works for me:

```
doc = {"updated_on": datetime.now(timezone.utc)}
res = es.index(index=es_index, doc_type='my_type',
               id=1, body=doc)
```

And is recognized by Kibana as a date.

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right path, your Python `datetime` needs to be serialized as an [ISO 8601-compliant](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) date string. So, you need to add a `CustomEncoder` in your `json.dumps()` call. First, declare your `CustomEncoder` as a subclass of `JSONEncoder` which will handle the transformation of `datetime` and `time` properties, but delegate the rest to its superclass:

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        if isinstance(obj, time):
            return obj.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        if hasattr(obj, 'to_json'):
            return obj.to_json()
        return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

And then you can use it in your `json.dumps` call, like this:

```
...
body=json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default, cls=CustomEncoder)
...
```

Comment: This solves the serialization of the datetime object: the field in the body is now "updated_at": {"$date": 1409505493017}. However, I get the same error, so the must be some other problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.serializer import serializer

serializer.dumps(your_dict)
```

Replace `your_dict` with your `Document().prepare()` or `document.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Making sure I timestamp to elastic using `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
doc = { 
   "timestamp": datetime.now(timezone.utc),
   #the rest of your data
}
```

Solved the problem of the time having a strange drift on elastic search.